# how to apend 4bytes number into a bash str variable and send it through nc

Tags: bash, netcat

say I have to send a message through nc (netcat)command. e.g

```
echo "hello world" | nc 127.0.0.1 9090
```

now i need to insert a int number(4 bytes int) before the string "hello world" meaning the string lenth before sending it through nc?

i.e. The protocol is "4bytes length + data" which i have no access to change

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf "\x00\x00\x00\x0bhello world" | nc 127.0.0.1 9090
```

The above example inserst the 4 byte value `0x0000000b` = 11 (big endian).